# Which is better get files - FTP or HTTP in iOS code?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, tomcat, ftp

I have to pull set of images from FTP.

I have tried same thing with a tomcat server by just giving the image's server url, it looks fast and good. To make a study on FTP file pulling from FTP server got a sample from apple [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html)

In the sample, there is a code to pull a image from FTP, but its too slow to pull an image.

Why its taking this much time for one image? if I have to get some set of images, i cant imagine the time delay?

Thanks,
Easwar

Comment: @PrakashDesai Accepted yours answer. Thanks

Comment: nice questions, i really have same one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Daniel states here](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/ftp-vs-http.html):

> What makes FTP faster:
>
> No added meta-data in the sent files, just the raw binary
>
> Never chunked encoding "overhead"
>
> What makes HTTP faster:
>
> reusing existing persistent connections make better TCP performance
>
> pipelining makes asking for multiple files from the same server faster
>
> (automatic) compression makes less data get sent
>
> no command/response flow minimizes extra round-trips
>
> Ultimately the net outcome of course differ depending on specific
>   details, but I would say that for single-shot static files, you won't
>   be able to measure a difference. For a single shot small file, you
>   might get it faster with FTP (unless the server is at a long
>   round-trip distance). When getting multiple files, HTTP should be the
>   faster one.

Use the following delegate method to track upload progress:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite

totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite gives me the upload percentage.
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes FTP slower:

you have to build the connection each time for each file.

In this I am not sure: the handschaking is done on port X ( 22 maybe) and the data tranfer is done in port Y ( 21 maybe)

What makes HTTP slower: 
The https header.

for one large file IO would use FTP, for a bunch  of small files HTTP, for 1 or a few small file : the code which I can copy-paste in 10 seconds :)

The FTP requires an FTP server, and set rights and the HTTP server usually already exist, if you care about the server side requirements.

Firewall: usually http granted, ftp denied

Answer (score 0):

FTP is far more complicated than HTTP:
1 several commands have to be executed to request the file
2 another TCP connection should be created to transfer the file data

so HTTP is the best choice if your application is latency sensitive.